unable to build Flutter project for iOS
Trying to build my Flutter app for iOS using this command "flutter build ipa --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols" results with Build failed with the following very long list that I don't have any clue where to start solving this issue where my app is building without any problem for Android devices.
Here is a full text files with the build error where I have also tried to update all errors with update iOS build from 9.0 to 17.0 at xcode runner.
https://github.com/asafgo/flutter-iOS-Build-Error/blob/main/ios_build_error.txt
Thanks for any help.

Finally I found the solution that works for me as it is probably a problem with Pod (Or CocaPod) version related to Xcode version.
On Mac open Terminal at the app folder and run this commands
cd ios  (the ios folder in the App)
pod deintegrate
pod install
flutter clean
flutter pub get
